# Creating an Object from 2 APIs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to create a single object with data coming from 2 apis. My problem is that when I create a property using the second api it comes as `Observable`. Is there a way to unrap that 'nested' observable?

```js
getUpcomingRes(): Observable<Reservation[]> {
    const upcomingResHolder = [];
    return this.config.connectReservations(this.hostID).pipe(
        map((resData: Reservation[]) => {
        for (const res of resData) {
            const arrivalDate = new Date(res.dateArrival);
            const today = new Date();
            if (arrivalDate > today) {
                const flightArrivalData = this.config.getFlightInformation(res.flightArrivalID).pipe(
                    map(snaps => {
                        return snaps.map(
                            snap => {
                                return {...snap};
                            }
                        );
                    })
                );
                const ob = {...res, flighArrData: flightArrivalData};
                upcomingResHolder.push(ob);
            }
        }
        return upcomingResHolder.sort((a, b) => b.dateArrival - a.dateArrival);
    }));
}
```

Comment: why you need to do `return snaps.map(
                            snap => {
                                return {...snap};
                            }
                        );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flightArrData` property was observable since there was no subscription to the `flightArrivalData` observable, but this behavior of nested subscriptions is discouraged and could be avoided with some simple operators like `mergeMap` and `switchMap`.

I have refactored your example to how I would have approach this:

```
getUpcomingRes(): Observable<Reservation[]> {
  const today = new Date();

  return this.config.connectReservations(this.hostID).pipe(
    switchMap(reservations =>
      from(reservations).pipe(
        filter(({ dateArrival }) => new Date(dateArrival) > today),
        this.populateReservationSnaps(),
        toArray()
      )
    ),
    map(reservations =>
      reservations.sort((a, b) => a.dateArrival - b.dateArrival)
    )
  );
}

populateReservationSnaps(): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<Reservation> {
  return (source: Observable<Reservation>) =>
    source.pipe(
      mergeMap(reservation =>
        this.config
          .getFlightInformation(reservation.flightArrivalID)
          .pipe(map(snaps => ({ ...reservation, flightArrData: snaps })))
      )
    );
}
```

Let's get over it step by step:
First, `populateReservationSnaps` is a simple [custom rxjs operator](https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/rxjs-custom-operators-f8b9aeab9631),
the return type: `MonoTypeOperatorFunction<Reservation>` only says that this operator acts on a stream of `Reservation` objects and return one as well.
The logic of this is pretty straight-forward, for each `Reservation` make a call to the second API and populate it with snaps.

Second, `getUpcomingRes` does the following:

- Retrieves the reservations array and flattens it using `from` operator
- Filters unwanted reservations - equivalent to your `if` statement
- Populates each `Reservation` with it's own snaps
- Accumulates the reservations to array and sorts it

The flatten is not a must, I just find it easier to operate on flattened streams.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make two api call simultaneously use combineLatest.

```
combineLatest(call1$, call2$).subscribe(([response1, response2]) => {
});
```

If you want to use the result of one api call in a second then use switchMap

```
call1$.pipe(switchMap(response1 => call2(response.property))).subscribe(response2 => {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For readability please consider separating some subrequirements. I did that in my example. To access the inner observable you need to use a higher map function like exhaustMap, switchMap, concatMap... I hope my example is clear to you.

```
getUpcomingRes(): Observable<Reservation[]> {
  const today = new Date();

  return this.config.connectReservations(this.hostID).pipe(
    map(reservations => reservations.filter(reservation => new Date(reservations.dateArrival) > today)),
    map(reservations => reservations.sort((a, b) => b.dateArrival - a.dateArrival)),
    switchMap(reservations => forkJoin([of(reservations), ...reservations.map(reservation => this.config.getFlightInformation(reservation.flightArrivalID))])),
    map(([reservations, ...snaps]) => reservations.map((reservation, i) => ({ ...reservation, flighArrData: snaps[i] }))),
  );
}
```